# Solving $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin^2(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Does the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin^2(\frac{1}{x})$ exist? My understanding is that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = DNE.$$
Is there any better way to view or solve it?

Comment: Technically it's not enough, because the product of two functions without limits may still have a limit. The fact that the two are equal helps, but not entirely. The fact that they are equal and continuous might be enough.

Comment: There certainly is a better way to solve it, since this is not a solution.

Comment: It is NOT generally true that if $L=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ then $L=(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))\cdot (\lim_{x\to a}g(x)).$.... It is true IF $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist in $\mathbb R.$ .... For example let $f(x)=0$ if $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q.$ Let $g(x)=1-x.$ Then $f(x)g(x)=0$ for all $x$ so $0=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)g(x).$ But  $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ don't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Consider the limit along these two sequences: for $n\geq 1$
$$x_n=\frac{1}{\pi n},\quad y_n=\frac{1}{\pi (n+1/2)}.$$
We have that $x_n\to 0$ and $y_n\to 0$. What are the limits:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin^2(1/x_n)=?\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin^2(1/y_n)=?$$

Comment: $ \lim \sin^2( \frac{1}{x_n}) = 0$ as n goes to infinity @Robert and the second limit is 1

Comment: @Jaynot Well done! Since these two limits are different, it follows that  $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin^2(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the actual problem $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\sin^2(\frac{1}{u})du$ that I was trying to solve. Does that suffices to say that the limit does not exceed? I would appreciate a little hint.  Since the limit of $ \sin^2( \frac{1}{x}$ does not exist, I am solving some trouble figuring this out.

Comment: @Jaynot No, the limit of with the integral is a different thing. If after applying Hopital the limit does not exist then this does NOT imply that the original limit does not exist too. The limit of with the integral should be $1/2$.

Comment: @Jaynot Note that $\sin(t)^2=(1-\cos(2t))/2$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jaynot: some more work is needed (after hint of Robert Z) to solve the limit of the integral. See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1551332/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Please see the new answer that I am adding below based on the new question.

Comment: @RobertZ you can also please check.

Comment: @Jaynot: I can see your deleted solution which is correct but needs to have more steps. The limit of $\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\cos(2/u)\,du$ as $x\to 0$ is $0$, but this fact is non-trivial and needs to be shown. The linked question in my previous comment deals with this problem. So you need to put some argument like that. It would be better if you ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Let the limit be $L$.

Then the equation $$\sin^2\frac1x=\left(L+\frac12\right)\bmod1$$ has infinitely many solutions in the neighborhood of $0$, such as $$x_k:=\dfrac1{\arcsin\sqrt{(L+\frac12)\bmod1}+2k\pi},$$ and

$$\left|\sin^2\frac1{x_k}-L\right|\ge\frac12.$$